# How do I enable title and target to link?

Tags: wysiwyg

Using Drupal 8, with the link icon in the wysiwyg editor, currently in the modal popup, it only allows URL.   I have to switch to source to add title and target attributes (outside website).    Is there a way to add those fields in the interface specifically that modal popup?  It looks like it's CKEditor.    My client is not as html savvy.

Let me know + steps to enable... thanks, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [D8 Editor Advanced link](https://www.drupal.org/project/editor_advanced_link) module.

Enhances the link Dialog in D8 CKEditor.
Allows to define the following attributes:

- title
- class
- id
- target
- rel